# Special Characters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, fonts, rendering

When using special characters in iOS apps, apps both built with Xcode/Swift as well as Xamarin I can see that iOS have trouble to render special characters in UILabel and UITextView.

Often the font gets rendered outside its component resulting the text being cropped. It can easily bee fixed with custom line height adjustments but, you will get an headache when building your application with support for accessibility when user can change the font size them selfs.

Anyone know how to handle this issue?

[image: Working font]

[image: Not working font]

[image: Not working font]

Comment: Are you using the SF-UIDisplay font? The standard one?

Comment: The top image that's woking is with the standard font, the other ones are Scene and Rockwell. Testing all my fonts I have installed I can see that about 5-8% of the fonts have issues in large text sizes.

Comment: It happened to me before. This is a font related issue unfortunately. You could subclass the UILabel to change the textArea by yourself

Comment: Hi, do you mean it also occurs with swift code in Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I can see the issue both in pure Swift projects as well as Xamarin projects

Comment: @CZ54 hmm, it's weird that it's not supported out of the box. I haven't found any discussions about it when I Google the issue either.

Comment: @bjorkblom Try to open your font with something like FontForge to review the glyph behaviour

Comment: Cheers @CZ54! FontForge show that its very clear that there are some issues with the font.